# Adding a space between the words "AirJordan" and "NewBalance" tabs - VUEJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I have a v-for and transition for a tab nav. I would like to add a space between the words **"Air(space here)Jordan"** and **"New(space here)Balance"** in the code below. Im using vue3 and tailwindcss. Its importing the component but when adding a space in thee desired words, it wont use the component anymore.

```
data() {
  return {
    currentTab: 'Adidas',
    tabs: ['Adidas', 'Airjordans', 'Nike', 'Newbalance', 'Reebok', 'Converse', 'Vans', 'Puma']
  }
}, }
```

my template code is shown below.

```
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="bg-[#f3f4f6]">
      <div class="max-w-7xl flex flex-1 overflow-auto whitespace-nowrap pl-4 pr-4 lg:pl-10 py-3 space-x-4 ">
      <button  class="font-rubikreg uppercase text-sm "
         v-for="tab in tabs"
         :key="tab"
         :class="['tab-button', { active: currentTab === tab } ]"
         @click="currentTab = tab"
       >
        {{ tab }}
      </button>
    </div>
```

i am importing components to display under each tab name. Then pushing to display when name is clicked. How can i add a space in NewBalance and AirJordans.

```
  import Airjordans from "./airjordans.vue";
  import Nike from "./nike.vue";
  import Adidas from "./adidas.vue";
  import Newbalance from "./newbalance.vue";
  import Reebok from "./reebok.vue";
  import Converse from "./converse.vue";
  import Vans from "./vans.vue";
  import Puma from "./puma.vue";
```

Comment: The code itself should be working, see [exapmle](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNpNUsFugzAM/RUrFzZphXsG1ardp2madhk7hGC6FEiQE+gqxL8vBFp6Sfz87Pg59sgOXRcPPTLOUitJdW6fawDVdoYcjEBYwQQVmRYiHxbNJP4FssRK9I0Pmn0ApXDi4fGKwGe6nvSGAWRPhNp9ioJDdChVKWz0tNFOFJbD943xMYrgZKgUOsA3VWO48QyFaISWAX4gFqaerVejByQbvF9r0nvfiujnWmVajHD5I01uPacO264RDkP/adE7ZzQMu8pQljOvDZQOEnMGvMbL4vTgRTZK1h5u7WULw2UjrPXMCEI6NSC/+wLIsmx+z8tgoSTAOHo8BW1psgjYpwUlgR7HLXeOSZM7wal1l2ZRHi+l1m8vhKyPZHpdcrCiaY1+3loPOeyJLcPetaKLT9ZovwohO18J3zG/jjFnfglmnLNf5zrLk8RWcl6gk40NHRNvxdRrp1qM0ba7gszZIvmHc7ZWntj0DzgCzzE=). Your problem is likely somewhere else

Comment: @Daniel OP probably wants to make it somewhat dynamic or idk. It's not very clear tbh.

Comment: @Daniel - i should be more clear. I am importing components that are named "adidas" "airjordan" but i would like to display "Air Jordan" in the tab. i have edited the code if you can have look. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to separate the components from the labels. Alternatively you could try to do some hack, but I'd say being explicit is better.

If you look into the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components) they show an example where they have an object of with the keys and Components matching

[link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```
const tabs = {
  Home,
  Posts,
  Archive
}
```

you can setup a similar thing, just define the key

example: [link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqNVUFu2zAQ/MpCOTgBLCtpih5YO2gOBXIp2kNvUVHIFGUzkUiBpJwEhv/eISkrclM3tgGDuzsczqzE9Ta5bdvZphMJS+aWG9k6ssJ17U2uZNNq4+hON4IqoxuazDIfePhkKP/Q1tmhHqJDwK3ha7l5pejjQ9CWjKho14NiiXLFtbKOeGeMUO5nsaSFx51PvIzJRa72CFcsLWpbbKI8uaPv9I2+5gkL4qc+258a1kEkVrtczbNoGnYRONG0deEEIqJ5KTfE68LaRZ6UotF5EvKoLDvnNDb4AJ9NWmkD0PnvqVdyQVIFRXkyQNijeAEC2XFyz34/QSGNrJMpmlFwB7HswPli4Ulp92vE8IXXkj+C4aBF41N6yUTbbdwO08FDFo/zxh1CrvEgFCiISS/J679/ZcWhQy8C/c08G7bEdmXoF1bzbNRFhNa91H458y2MT6jSyqVV0cj6hZEtlE2tMLL67GtLbUphGF21z2R1LUs6E0KMSqkpStlZRh/a55Bui7KUaoXEJfZc4yekm8KspEqdbkEmmnFuqeG8YfRxj+1wPjTUgjtGCp5CVm+EqWr9lD4zKjqnkUTz4OT1YUU/g4JPEHC1J+3lQkBai8oNuq/f1o1crY8BDlrBOQ8lPBirUWq1VE6YCC/448roTpWMzqpL//2X6RR043w4e0jD4MgeW/seRJMH9OLSf9/gZ/G9PWFDDznucOhp3894V8O7lEyTODXSpmhnD1YrDK/+6scCbh6LJ/gcpomP82TtXGtZltmK++nzYGfarDKsZqZTTmKyCdukS6Of8D6AOE/CuOg5MiTRjRQ3AqKF+R/nX9A3vJ4Wjnawsp+ofgAfnz/xzkU1YSAPl+/I3QPzMItPp47D/ATu0RA/nX3/T/Au/+4PoVo44A==)

```js
const tabs = {
  "H O M E": Home,
  Archive,
  Posts,
}
```

My preference, however, would be to be more explicit and use an array like this

```js
const tabs = [
  {label: 'Adidas', component: Adidas},
  {label: 'Air jordans', component: AirJordans},
  // etc...
];
```

and then have `currentTab` use the index

full example
[link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
<script>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import Adidas from './Adidas.vue';
  import AirJordans from './AirJordans.vue';

  const tabs = [
    {label: 'Adidas', component: Adidas},
    {label: 'Air jordans', component: AirJordans},
  ];
  
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        currentTab: 0,
      }
    },
    setup(){
      return {tabs}
    }
  }
</script>
<template>
  <button v-for="(tab,i) in tabs" :key="i" @click="currentTab=i" :class="{ active: currentTab === i }">
    {{tab.label}}
  </button>
  <component v-bind:is="tabs[currentTab].component"></component>
</template>
<style>
  .active{
    background: salmon;
  }
</style>
```